# FormCollections missing from ASP.Net 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, beta, formcollection

What happened to FormCollections from `System.Web.Mvc`?  In the past I would use something like this `string value = data.GetValues(key).FirstOrDefault();` where data is a formcollection. Now when I try to implement a FormCollection it comes from `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Internal`. Which doesnt contain the GetValues method.

I'm currently using beta 8 of MVC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like the form collection is now represented by the interface [`IFormCollection`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/IFormCollection.cs) which inherits from [`IReadableStringCollection`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/IReadableStringCollection.cs) which is enumerable over the keys and values in the form collection passed in the http request. It can also be used to get to the values for a key through indexing:

```
var myValues = this.Request.Form[someKey];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access it via `Request.Form` in controllers. Instead of `GetValues` method, those values are accessed from it's indexer as:

```
var id = Request.Form["id"];
```

**PS:** If the given key does not exist, it does not return null or throw any exception. It returns `StringValues.Empty` instead.